# How do I query a postgres-db view with psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I've got `psycopg2` running and I can successfully query tables of my database. This is a working example of querying the table `my_table`:

```
import psycopg2
try:
  conn_string="dbname='my_dbname' user='user' host='localhost' password='password'"
  print "Connecting to database\n->%s" % (conn_string)

  conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
  print "connection succeeded"
except:
  print "no connection to db"

cur = conn.cursor()

try:
  cur.execute(""" SELECT *  from my_table; """)

  records = cur.fetchall()
  cur.close()

except:
  print "Query not possible"
```

Question: How can I query a view, let it be called `my_view`, within the same database `my_dbname`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you'd query a table. From a `SELECT` point of view, a `VIEW` is the exact same thing as a `TABLE`:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * from my_view")
```

Note that you generally do *not* want to use a black `except:`. Catch a specific exception if you have to, but you are usually better off not catching the exception *at all* rather than block all feedback on errors as you've done here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem I actually have has nothing to to whether I query a table or a view. The view I created within my database had an other owner (not "user" as in "conn_string"). So after changing user in "conn_string" the query works.

Comment: @C.B.: I suspected there might be something else going on but your question didn't include any detail. Updated my answer with a remark towards your exception handling, which would not have helped you diagnose this problem.

Comment: for not "swallowing" exceptions +1